# how to compare two currency in jquery with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare, currency

I have two inputs that when I start typing number, it automatically changes to currency, like this:

1,000 
10,000 
100,000 
1,000,000

so how do you compare these two inputs? 
Because it is a comma, it creates a comparative problem.

```
function priceCompare() {
    var price_meterVal;
    var priceVal;
    $("#price_meter").on("keyup",function () {
        price_meterVal = $($("#price_meter")).val().replace(/,/g, '');
    });
    $("#price").on("keyup",function () {
        priceVal = $($("#price")).val().replace(/,/g, '');
    });

    if (priceVal <= price_meterVal){
        $("#priceError").html('قیمت کل ملک نمی تواند کمتر از قیمت متری باشد.');
        contractStatus = false;
    }else {
        contractStatus = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace all the commas with empty strings, then compare

Comment: please share the html

Comment: Why are you wrapping a jQuery object in another jQuery object? `$($("#price_meter))` is the same as `$("#price_meter")`... Also, the code you've shared replaces commas with empty strings and should therefore work for comparison. Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to do it. I put the examples you posted in an array to avoid having 4 more variables.

```js
const sampleInputs = [ '1,000', '10,000', '100,000', '1,000,000' ]

// + is a shortcut to convert to a number

// split at commas
const splitMethod = +sampleInputs[0].split(',').join('')

// match digits
const regexOne = +(sampleInputs[1].match(/\d/g) || []).join('')

// replace commas
const regexTwo = +sampleInputs[2].replace(/,/g, '')

// filter
const fi = +sampleInputs[3]
  .split('')
  .filter(n => n !== ',')
  .join('')


console.log('splitMethod', splitMethod)

console.log('regexOne', regexOne)

console.log('regexTwo', regexTwo)

console.log('filter', fi)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below line of code

```
function comparecurrent(cur1, cur2) {
        if (parseInt(cur1.replace(/,/g, '')) > parseInt(cur2.replace(/,/g, ''))) {
            alert("currency 1");
        }
        else if (parseInt(cur1.replace(/,/g, '')) < parseInt(cur2.replace(/,/g, ''))) 
        {
            alert("currency 2");
        }
        else {
            alert('equal');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`let newInteger = parseInt(numberString.split(",").join(''));`

I'm assuming you want it to be a number at the end to compare to other numbers. If you'd like to keep it a string `let newString = numberString.split(",").join('');`